# Breeze js with aspnet identity?`

Tags: breeze, asp.net-identity

Has anyone managed to get Breeze js working with the aspnet identity webapi 2?  The only example I've seen with ajax and webapi 2 is the durandal 451 project which uses jquery ajax calls and a separate controller: https://github.com/Useful-Software-Solutions-Ltd/Durandal451/blob/master/Durandal451v2/Controllers/AccountController.cs

Would it just be a case of copying all these methods into the breezecontroller?

Answer (score 0):

NO. Don't do that. Don't combine auth concerns with data access concerns in the same controller.

A *Breeze* Web API controller is ... a Web API Controller. Use the same techniques that are appropriate for *any* Web API controller. I suggest you start down this road by [reading the Web API Security documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security). Everything you learn there ... and thereafter ... will apply.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you're using for spa framework but I managed to run angular, breeze, and webapi2 auth at the same project. I cant show you a working example for now, it's a private project. if I got time, gonna put a super simple example to github.

Here is how I did it;
Started using this project as a boiler plate for angular and oauth web api, 
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

and John Papa's hottowel mixing after that for again angular and breezejs.

What you need to understand is breeze controller is just a controller and has nothing to do with auth as Ward mentioned below.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can vouch for osmancelik's answer.  I did the exact same thing.  I used the HotTowel template and implemented the code from http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ together with breeze. Works like a charm.

I ran into one problem though.  The token authentication code adds a service to httpProvider interceptors.

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
    });
```

This works perfectly for default angular ajax calls but not for breeze (when you start from the HotTowel template)  Adding the breeze.angular.js service was all that I needed to do to fix this.